# Change query to replace string by values in table of replacement

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.3, alias, replace

To store emails list I have two quite simple tables, domain and mailbox, so **user@domain.com** is stored as:

**domain**

| id | domain_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | domain.com |

**mailbox**

| id | local_part | domain_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | user | 1 |

(*local_part* is email part to the left of '@' sign, and *domain_id* refers to id value of domain in **domain** table).

Until this point, all is simple, and I can **list all boxes** like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(m.local_part, '@', d.domain_name) 
FROM domain d, mailbox m 
WHERE m.domain_id=d.id
```

Now I need to add some way to support domain alias (so e.g. domain.net become alias of domain.com).

So I create table domain_alias:

| domain_old | domain_new |
| --- | --- |
| domain.com | domain.net |

Now I try to modify above query so all boxes in domain_old be shown as domain_new boxes (e.g. instead of user@domain.com this query yields user@domain.net).

I suspect this might be not that hard but I must be missed something so please advice!

P.S. I do that with MariaDB 10.3.

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Comment: What database system and version?

Comment: @J.D. I use MySQL (more to say, MariaDB 10.3)

Comment: What is a "box"?  It is not a database term.

Comment: @RickJames Surely box is not a DB term, but this is the objects I track in my DB. Anyway, the problem is to create right query for the DB data